# Interested to know ssh client used in nitrous.io

Tags: ssh, nitrousio

What is ssh client used in Nitrous.io. I am interested to know about ssh clients and I have seen ssh client used in Nitrous web site

Answer (score 2):

I didn't tested, but if found this ssh2 repository from them: https://github.com/nitrous-io/ssh2

As it says "An SSH2 client module written in pure JavaScript for node.js." Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Nitrous.io ssh client. I assume they are using some sort of web based ssh client. But you can always read the MAN pages for ssh, [ssh(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) and  http://www.openssh.org/manual.html, to learn the basics of ssh.